# Resume activity from a android tv recommendation

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-lifecycle, android-tv, leanback

I have some troubles with the management of recommendations (notifications) on an Android TV with the Leanback Launcher.

I use the google sample here to implement my own : https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback

Expected result :

- I'm on my activity "MainActivity" (with a webview)
- I press HOME, so I'm on the Leanback launcher with recommendation include mines.
- I press on one of them
- Resume activity "MainActivity" without recreate it with a new Intent with a new extra.

Actually, The resume of the activity without reload the activity works fine, below the creation of the PendingIntent :

```
private PendingIntent buildPendingIntent(Parcelable media, int id) {
        Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        detailsIntent.putExtra("media", media);
        detailsIntent.putExtra("id", id);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(detailsIntent);

        return stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Current result :

- I'm on my activity "MainActivity" (with a webview)
- I press HOME, so I'm on the Leanback launcher with recommendation include mines.
- I press on one of them
- My activity receive "onNewIntent" event by in the extrat intent values I have always the same media.

This solution doesn't work, because Google said in a comment of the sample code :

```
// Ensure a unique PendingIntents, otherwise all recommendations end up with the same 
// PendingIntent

detailsIntent.setAction(movie.getId());
```

So to differentiate all recommandations, I have to set Action with an ID, else, it will be always the last pendingintent sent to my activity. It's my current behavior, I receive in "onNewIntent" always the same "media" and "id" in the intent (the last one), whatever on which recommendation I click, I always get the same Intent.

But if I set the action with an "id", the activity "MainActivity" is recreated, so the resume failed, and the context of my webview is cleared my webview is reloaded :( but I get the good intent with the good media in the extra intent values.

Have you a solution to help me to have the behavior I want ?

To simplify my question, how can I resume my Activity B from a recommendation with the good pendingintent without reload my activity ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I don't think it's the good one but it works for my case.

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, id, detailsIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
return pIntent;
```

So, If I set the "resquetCode" with the id, so Android think it's a different Activity and resume it without recreate a new  one.